# Pass element ID to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen many threads related to my question title.

Here is HTML Codes :

```
<button id="button1" class="MetroBtn" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">Btn1</button>
<button id="button2" class="MetroBtn" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">Btn2</button>
<button id="button3" class="MetroBtn" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">Btn3</button>
<button id="button4" class="MetroBtn" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">Btn4</button>
```

And a very simple JS function is here :

```
function myFunc(id){
        alert(id);
}
```

You can see in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7kRt/).

The problem is :

I have no idea, maybe doesn't pass `this.id` to `myFunc` function, or some problem else.

What's the problem ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Took your fiddle and changed 1 thing, this worked: http://jsfiddle.net/h7kRt/2/

Comment: @MisterBla what did you change? It looks identical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In jsFiddle by default the code you type into the script block is wrapped in a function executed on window.onload:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    window.onload = function () {
        function myFunc(id){
            alert(id);     
        }
    }
//]]>  
</script>
```

Because of this, your function `myFunc` is not in the global scope so is not available to your html buttons. By changing the option to `No-wrap in <head>` as Sergio suggests your code isn't wrapped:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    function myFunc(id){
       alert(id);     
    }
//]]>  
</script>
```

and so the function is in the global scope and available to your html buttons.

Comment: In my case, if i click the button i have set to display id,  screenshot : https://snag.gy/7bzEWN.jpg  code : https://www.pastiebin.com/5d35674e2fc31

Answer (score 17):

This'll work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunc(id)
            {
                alert(id);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="button1" class="MetroBtn" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">Btn1</button>
        <button id="button2" class="MetroBtn" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">Btn2</button>
        <button id="button3" class="MetroBtn" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">Btn3</button>
        <button id="button4" class="MetroBtn" onClick="myFunc(this.id);">Btn4</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script>
            function passBtnID(id) {
                alert("You Pressed:  " + id);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="mybtn1" onclick="passBtnID('mybtn1')">Press me</button><br><br>
        <button id="mybtn2" onclick="passBtnID('mybtn2')">Press me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/h7kRt/1/,

you should change in jsfiddle on top-left to `No-wrap in <head>`

Your code looks good and it will work inside a normal page. In jsfiddle your function was being defined inside a load handler and thus is in a different scope. By changing to No-wrap you have it in the global scope and can use it as you wanted.

Comment: Also it would be nice to actually include code here, not to rely on 3rd party site.

Comment: @Yossarian, what code? I changed no code, he just forgot to put "No-wrap" in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Sergio In my case, if i click the button i have set to display id,  screenshot : https://snag.gy/7bzEWN.jpg  code : https://www.pastiebin.com/5d35674e2fc31

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was as simple as just not knowing Javascript well. I was trying to pass the name of the id using double quotes, when I should have been using single. And it worked fine.

This worked:

```
validateSelectizeDropdown('#PartCondition')
```

This did not:

```
validateSelectizeDropdown("#PartCondition")
```

And the function:

```
    function validateSelectizeDropdown(name) {
    if ($(name).val() === "") {
         //do something
    }
}
```