# Change td color by id link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the background of `<td>`'s content on kind of link calling.

**This is the menu code:**

```
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a id="FV Orders_sub" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">Inserisci Contratto<b class="caret"></b></a>
                          <ul id="FV Orders_sub" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                               <a href="index.php?module=SalesOrder&view=Edit&parenttab=FV Orders" id="nuovocontrattoFV">Nuovo Contratto</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                               <a href="index.php?module=SalesOrder&view=List&viewname=50" id="nuovocontrattoBIKE">Nuovo contratto bike</a>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                    </li>
```

**This is the content code:**

```
            <td class="fieldLabel {$WIDTHTYPE}" id="fieldlabel">
                {if $isReferenceField neq "reference"}<label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px">{/if}
                    {if $FIELD_MODEL->isMandatory() eq true && $isReferenceField neq "reference"} <span class="redColor">*</span> {/if}
                    {if $isReferenceField eq "reference"}
                        {assign var="REFERENCE_LIST" value=$FIELD_MODEL->getReferenceList()}
                        {assign var="REFERENCE_LIST_COUNT" value=count($REFERENCE_LIST)}
                        {if $REFERENCE_LIST_COUNT > 1}
                            {assign var="DISPLAYID" value=$FIELD_MODEL->get('fieldvalue')}
                            {assign var="REFERENCED_MODULE_STRUCT" value=$FIELD_MODEL->getUITypeModel()->getReferenceModule($DISPLAYID)}
                            {if !empty($REFERENCED_MODULE_STRUCT)}
                                {assign var="REFERENCED_MODULE_NAME" value=$REFERENCED_MODULE_STRUCT->get('name')}
                            {/if}
                            <span class="pull-right">
                                {if $FIELD_MODEL->isMandatory() eq true} <span class="redColor">*</span> {/if}
                                <select class="chzn-select referenceModulesList streched" style="width:140px;">
                                    <optgroup>
                                        {foreach key=index item=value from=$REFERENCE_LIST}
                                            <option value="{$value}" {if $value eq $REFERENCED_MODULE_NAME} selected {/if}>{vtranslate($value, $MODULE)}</option>
                                        {/foreach}
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </span>
                        {else}
                            <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px">{if $FIELD_MODEL->isMandatory() eq true} <span class="redColor">*</span> {/if}{vtranslate($FIELD_MODEL->get('label'), $MODULE)}</label>
                        {/if}
                    {else if $FIELD_MODEL->get('uitype') eq "83"}
                        {include file=vtemplate_path($FIELD_MODEL->getUITypeModel()->getTemplateName(),$MODULE) COUNTER=$COUNTER}
                    {else}
                        {vtranslate($FIELD_MODEL->get('label'), $MODULE)}
                    {/if}
                {if $isReferenceField neq "reference"}</label>{/if}
            </td>
```

I have tried to find something on web but there's nothing.
I need a different background color for my td element when the user clicks it.

Comment: Do you need to change to different colors based on different link? Or same color regardless?

Comment: yes different colors on different link for same form table

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: http://jsbin.com/zusesuke/1/. Try clicking on colors

Comment: the right combination that i'm looking for is how suggested from farmerjoe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through javascript directly by adding an `event listener` to the element on the `click` event.

This can be done by calling the `addEventListener` method on the element, which you can retrieve by `id` by calling `getElementById` on the `document`.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">
            <div>
                <span>Here is my td!</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("td1").addEventListener("click",
    function() {
        this.style.background="red";                                                    
    }
);
```

And a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/S86b7/)

And a [more fun example](http://jsfiddle.net/S86b7/6/)

So adapted to what looks like your `td`'s `id`:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldLabel {$WIDTHTYPE}" id="fieldlabel">
            <!-- More elements here -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("fieldlabel").addEventListener("click",
    function() {
        this.style.background="red";                                                    
    }
);
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to have individual behavior for unique ids on your menu items to affect the same `<td>` element, then you could assign each button some `click` event behavior to each `link` and have that function either directly change the color or create a wrapper function which handles them all.  I would recommend the second approach because if you wish to make changes later on it is easier to change A function then having to go through a larger portion of your code.

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a id="FV Orders_sub" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">Inserisci Contratto<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul id="FV Orders_sub" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li> <a href="#index.php?module=SalesOrder&view=Edit&parenttab=FV Orders" id="nuovocontrattoFV">Nuovo Contratto</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#index.php?module=SalesOrder&view=List&viewname=50" id="nuovocontrattoBIKE">Nuovo contratto bike</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
</li>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">
            <div> <span>Here is my td!</span>

                <!-- More Stuff Here-->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("nuovocontrattoFV").addEventListener("click",

function () {
    switchTDBackgroundColor(this.id);
});

document.getElementById("nuovocontrattoBIKE").addEventListener("click",

function () {
    switchTDBackgroundColor(this.id);
});

function switchTDBackgroundColor(id) {
    var color = "white"; // A default setting
    if (id == "nuovocontrattoBIKE") {
        color = "blue";
    } else if (id == "nuovocontrattoFV") {
        color = "red";
    }
    document.getElementById("td1").style["background-color"] = color;
}
```

This way if you wanted to have more options you could simply modify the code by adding this event handler:

```
document.getElementById("nuovocontrattoFV").addEventListener("click",
    function () {
        switchTDBackgroundColor(this.id);
    }
);

document.getElementById("nuovocontrattoBIKE").addEventListener("click",
 function () {
        switchTDBackgroundColor(this.id);
    }
);

// ONLY HAVE TO CHANGE THE ARGUMENT FOR getElementById
document.getElementById("newListItem").addEventListener("click",
 function () {
        switchTDBackgroundColor(this.id);
    }
);

function switchTDBackgroundColor(id) {
    var color = "white"; // A default setting
    if (id == "nuovocontrattoBIKE") {
        color = "blue";
    } else if (id == "nuovocontrattoFV") {
        color = "red";
    } else if (id == "newListItem") { // Just Add this check 
        color = "yellow";             // And set to desired color
    }
    document.getElementById("fieldlabel").style["background-color"] = color;
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/farmerjoe19/S86b7/11/) *Note: I added hashtags to the `href` on the links in the jsfiddle example, this was only to avoid redirects so just the color change behavior is higlighted*

**EDIT 2:**

For a jQuery adaptation

```
$("#nuovocontrattoFV").click(
    function () {
        switchTDBackgroundColor($(this).attr("id"));
    }
);

$("#nuovocontrattoBIKE").click(
    function () {
        switchTDBackgroundColor($(this).attr("id"));
    }
);

// ONLY HAVE TO CHANGE THE ARGUMENT FOR getElementById
$("#newListItem").click(
    function () {
        switchTDBackgroundColor($(this).attr("id"));
    }
);

function switchTDBackgroundColor(id) {
    var color = "white"; // A default setting
    if (id == "nuovocontrattoBIKE") {
        color = "blue";
    } else if (id == "nuovocontrattoFV") {
        color = "red";
    } else if (id == "newListItem") { // Just Add this check 
        color = "yellow";             // And set to desired color
    }
    $("#fieldlabel").css("background-color",color);
}
```

And [jsfiddle for the jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/farmerjoe19/S86b7/13/)

Comment: that what i need is something like:

    if id="nuovocontrattoFV"

    then td set fieldlabel background-color=yellow

    If id="nuovocontrattoBIKE"
   
    then set fieldlabel td background-color=red

Comment: I made an edit to encompass your comment, let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, this right what i'm looking for. But it dosen't work... why?

Comment: @JoeWeb No problem! Glad to help, I edited the Last JSFiddle link and checked, it works on my browser, what is not functioning for you?

Comment: sorry it never work for me... i don't know why. i'm trying on jsfiddle your last version and it never work with firefox. I try same with chrome and it work. last i try script including it like js and never work on my website. Any idea?

Comment: I think javascript never work on this pages... I think is beter to use jquery function to do this.. what do you think about?

Comment: @JoeWeb I made an update with a jQuery adaptation, hopefully this should eliminate any bvrowser specific problems...let me know how it goes

Comment: Thank you @farmerjoe this works beter but only on static pages. I'm using Vtiger and this code work only after two clicks. So i'm thinking

Comment: to add something like this: $("#nuovocontrattoFV").click(function () {
    switchTDBackgroundColor($(this).attr("id"));
});
$("#nuovocontrattoBIKE").click(function () {
    switchTDBackgroundColor($(this).attr("id"));
});

function switchTDBackgroundColor(id) {
    var color = "white"; // A default setting
    if (id == "nuovocontrattoBIKE") {
        color = "blue";
    } else if (id == "nuovocontrattoFV") {
        color = "red";
    }
    $("#fieldlabel").removeClass('fieldLabel').addClass("background-color",color);
}

Comment: do you think is correct @farmerjoe if i use addClass ?

Comment: @JoeWeb I think you could use `addClass`, but I do not think that is the correct way to go about doing so.  That seems strange that the `jQuery` behavior should stop after a couple working iterations, is there any exception being raised? have you looked at the console?

Comment: @JoeWeb I do not think the `addClass`/`removeClass` strategy works the way you would like it to.  By calling `$("#fieldlabel").removeClass('fieldLabel')` you will remove the class `fieldLabel` from `td` altogether, and lose any stylings you have from that class.  Your call to `.addClass("background-color",color)` also does not make much sense, the addClass method accepts the string of a predefined css class and does not work with individual `style` attributes. If you want to use the `addClass`/`removeClass` scheme, see my exmaple here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farmerjoe19/K5ZYm/2/)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<td class="fieldLabel" id="fieldlabel">
    <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px">
        <span class="redColor">*</span>
        <span class="pull-right">
            <span class="redColor">*</span>
            <select class="chzn-select referenceModulesList streched" style="width:140px;">
                <optgroup>
                    <option value=""></option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </span>
        <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px"><span class="redColor">*</span></label>
    </label>
</td>
```

My first issue is with the HTML structure. While it is technically feasible, nesting a `<label>` inside another `<label>` is bad practice. Or did I misinterpret the nested if statements in your example? If you can post an example of the output, rather than the template code, it might be clearer.

Placing that aside, for the moment, your best bet would be to use JavaScript to toggle a class (both for performance and for maintainability -- you should never have styles inline in your HTML, nor inline in your JavaScript unless you absolutely cannot avoid it).

**CSS:**

```
td.highlighted {
    background-color: #AAF; /* a nice, pleasing shade of purple */
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
window.util = (function() {
    return {
        // class manipulation from http://www.openjs.com/scripts/dom/class_manipulation.php
        // taken from https://gist.github.com/jbergantine/1165817
        hasClass: function(ele,cls) {
            return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
        },
        addClass: function(ele,cls) {
            if (!this.hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
        },
        removeClass: function(ele,cls) {
            if (this.hasClass(ele,cls)) {
                var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
                ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
            }
        }
    };
})();

var tdClick = function(event) {
    var util = window.util;
    // if clicked element is a highlightable <td>
    if (util.hasClass(event.toElement, "clickToHighlight")) {
        // toggle class
        if (util.hasClass(event.toElement, "highlighted")) {
            util.removeClass(event.toElement, "highlighted");
        } else {
            util.addClass(event.toElement, "highlighted");
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("tableId").addEventListener("click", tdClick);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adriantp/6HNDC/3/)

...or if you prefer **jQuery:**

```
$("#tableId").on("click", ".clickToHighlight", function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is(".clickToHighlight")) {
        $this.toggleClass("highlighted");
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adriantp/6HNDC/4/)

You'll notice I'm attaching the event handler to the table itself. This is because, with a large enough table, having an event attached directly to each element could cause performance issues, and if the table can be updated via AJAX, then you have yet another problem of needing to append new event handlers to each newly-generated table cell. The technique I'm using is called "event delegation," wherein we delegate the event listener to a parent element, where it will process every click event and filter out which ones are important and act on them, as opposed to having dozens or hundreds of individual listeners.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Javascript onclick Event to trigger the change. In your Javascript function, you can pass the element into the function.

HTML

```
<td class="fieldLabel {$WIDTHTYPE}" id="fieldlabel" onclick="changeTD(this);">
```

Javascript

```
function changeTD(x)
{
    x.style.color="red";
}
```

or...

```
function changeTD(x)
{
    x.style.color="#00ff00";
}
```

or...

```
function changeTD(x)
{
    x.style.color="rgb(0,0,255)";
}
```

[onclick Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

[Pass element to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292176/pass-element-id-to-javascript-function)

[CSS Color](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp)

[Change Style with Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Comment: thanks, but i need to change color of same td for different link calling.