# How pass parameter to a javascript onclick function.No jquery please

Tags: javascript

I have created a button and onclick of it I want to pass the attribute values to a function

```
<button type="button"  name="createTask" id="createTask" class="createButton" onclick="Components.init(this)" >Add Task</button>
```

I also have a javascript function located in an external js file

```
var Components = function(attributes){
var attributed = attributes;
 var _init = function(){
    console.log("Method Executing:Compnents.init")
    alert(attributes.id)        

    }
return {
    init:_init,

    }
}()
```

But alerting this is showing undefined.How do I pass parameter to this javascript function.
    I have included this component.js which has this function at bottom of the html body

Comment: You seem to be doing things in the wrong order... `attributes` argument should be in the *inner* function, surely?

Comment: Where have you refereed the external file? And Components.init(this) could you please explain?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I am creating a closure where inner function have access to a outer variable

Comment: @Dnyanesh 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292176/pass-element-id-to-javascript-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>

var Components = function(){

var attributes;

var _init = function(elm){
    attributes = elm.attributes;
    console.log("Method Executing:Compnents.init")
    console.log(attributes.id.value);        
}

return {
    init:_init,
}

}();

</script>
```

Comment: The _init function expects a parameter.. you are passing to init. In your original code, you should remove "attributes" from Components = function() to _init = function(attributes)

Comment: @Joenesy it is a closure

Comment: Code–only answers are not that helpful. You should explain the OP's problem and how to go about fixing it, then show some code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
Components = {
 init: function(component) {
    console.log("Method Executing:Components.init");
    alert(component.id);
 }
};
```

```html
<button type="button"  name="createTask" id="createTask" class="createButton" onclick="Components.init(this)" >Add Task</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
var Components = function(attributes){
```

by convention, functions starting with a capital letter are reserved for constructors. It's considerate to wraps an IIFE in parenthesis so it's clear that it's an IIFE from the start.

The variable *attributes* is included in the formal parameter list, which is effectively the same as declaring it. No parameter is passed to it, so its value is *undefined*. The following declaration therefore does nothing.

```
  var attributed = attributes;
```

.

```
  var _init = function(){
    console.log("Method Executing:Compnents.init")
    alert(attributes.id)
```

Since *attributes* is undefined, attempting to access the *id* property will throw an error.

```
  }
  return {
    init:_init,
  }
```

There is a trailing comma (,) that is a syntax error. It's also considered a good idea to always use semicolons.

```
}()
```

Ah, finally, it's an IIFE.

A fixed version of the code:

```
var components = (function() {
  var _init = function(attributes) {
    console.log("Method Executing:Compnents.init");
    alert(attributes.id);      
  };
  return {
    init:_init
  };
}());
```

And the call must be changed to reflect the new function name:

```
<button id="createTask" onclick="components.init(this)" >Add Task</button>
```

If you wish to persist the value passed in in a closure, you need another parameter:

```
var components = (function() {
  var storedAttributes;

  var _init = function(attributes) {
    storedAttributes = attributes;
    console.log("Method Executing:Compnents.init");
    alert(attributes.id);      
  };

  var _foo = function() {
    //  Do stuff with attributes
  };

  return {
    init: _init,
    foo: _foo
  };
}());
```