# Pass id from eventlistener to function

Tags: javascript

Many answers pertaining to the solution of how to pass an id from an event listener to a function, *in pure javascript,*  include the use of the **THIS** "function"

**see** [Pass element ID to Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292176/pass-element-id-to-javascript-function)

I wanted to include this in my code, but it unfortunately does not seem to work in my case.

***Some context***: On my page; there are 4 options, only 1 option is always correct, which one that is changes.  The code here needs to
 remove the previous event listener (which listens if the clicked
 answer was correct) before assigning another event listener in order
 to not bug out the incorrect counters because the correct option has
 changed position and also div id

Relevant code:

```
function AvAnswers(){
//changing the options



for(i = 0; i<4; i){
  rngIndex[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  else{
    document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = ABCD[i] + AnswerArray[rngIndex[i]];
    if (rngIndex[i] == 3) {
      document.getElementById(i).addEventListener("click", Correct(this.id) );
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById(i).addEventListener("click", Incorrect(this.id) );
    }
    i++;
  }
}             //end of a for loop
}             //end of a function

function Correct(id){
  alert('good nice');
  document.getElementById(id).removeEventListener("click", Correct(this.id));
  AvAnswers();//reset options
}
function Incorrect(id){
  incorrect++
  alert(incorrect + " incorrect")
  document.getElementById(id).removeEventListener("click", Incorrect(this.id));
}
```

and this is the error message I get out of it.

> ***Error Message:*** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null

**The problem:**
Something to do with the scope of the variables or syntax? Honestly, no idea. The div which the event listener is added to is clickable. (so yes it does exist.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add enough relevant code so that we can execute what you have and replicate the issue.

Comment: BTW, you are not passing functions to neither `addEventListener` nor `removeEventListener`. You are passing `undefined`s

Comment: Listeners should be function expressions, not their evaluations.

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be in `Correct(this.id)`? Also `for(...)` followed by `else {...` makes zero sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is calling `Correct(this.id)` and `Incorrect(this.id)` immediately (it's not waiting for `click` events. To configure an event listener, you must  a function reference. You are passing the return value from the invocation of calling `Correct` or `Incorrect` and neither of those functions return a value, so the `click` handler is not being assigned.

Also, the first argument that an event listener receives is always a reference to the event itself.

To solve this problem, you can wrap the invocations in an anonymous function and pass along the `event` reference to the actual handlers.

As for the error message you are receiving, you are getting this because `this` inside of `AvAnswers` is not referencing a DOM element and so `this.id` is not a valid `id` of any DOM element. You should add `console.log(this.id)` to find out what it is in fact picking up.

You'll have to reevaluate how `AvAnswers` is being invoked and either change that invocation context so that `this` has the proper reference or find an alternative way to capture the correct `id`.

```
  else{
    document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = ABCD[i] + AnswerArray[rngIndex[i]];
    if (rngIndex[i] == 3) {
      // Notice that the actual call to Correct is wrapped:
      document.getElementById(i).addEventListener("click", function(event){
        Correct(event, this.id);
      });
    }
    else{
      // Notice that the actual call to Incorrect is wrapped:
      document.getElementById(i).addEventListener("click", function(){
        Incorrect(this.id);
      });
    }
    i++;
  }
}             //end of a for loop
}             //end of a function

function Correct(event, id){
  alert('good nice');
  document.getElementById(id).removeEventListener("click", Correct(this.id));
  drawClock();
}
function Incorrect(event, id){
  incorrect++
  alert(incorrect + " incorrect")
  document.getElementById(id).removeEventListener("click", Correct(this.id));
}
```

Comment: You missed the ones inside the functions. BTW the error says that `document.getElementById(i)` yields `null`

Answer (score 1):

The eventlistener needs to be a function, so what you need to do is make your functions return an anonymous function like so:

```
function Correct(id){
  return function() {
    alert('good nice');
    document.getElementById(id).removeEventListener("click", this);
    doFunction();//reset options
  }
}
```

That will let the id be in scope when the event fires, but the inner function is what actually gets called. Also, the eventlistener you're removing is the one you're inside, so `this` should work for that.

Also, your reference to `this.id` is scoped to your function `AvAnswers`, which is no good for your purpose, since you're really looking for the current element id, I think.  Your code is incomplete, but based on context, I think you might be better using the variable `i`, if it's working for getting the elements in the loop as your example implies.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a function **reference** to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`, not a function **call**.

As of now you are passing the **return value** of `Correct(this.id)` and `Incorrect(this.id)`, both of which don't have an explicit `return` value, which means they return `undefined`.

So basically you are doing this:

```
document.getElementById(i).addEventListener("click", undefined);
```

That being said, this also causes the error message you've shown:

```
document.getElementById(i).addEventListener("click", Correct(this.id));
```

That line immediately calls the function `Correct()` and passes `this.id` as a parameter. In your function you accept a parameter `id` and use it here:

```
document.getElementById(id).removeEventListener("click", Correct(this.id));
```

The error you're getting means that `document.getElementById(id)` does not find an element, which is why it returns `null`. This means that `this.id` in your function **call** is not what you expect it to be (I assume it's `undefined`), which in return means that `this` is not what you expect it to be.