# How can i put id to function in html

Tags: javascript, html

I`ve HTML

```
 <a class="nav-link" id="sell" (click)="renderView(id)" 

 <a class="nav-link" id="event" (click)="renderView(id)"
```

and JS

```
renderView(id) {
    switch (id) {
      case 'detailInfo':
        console.log('detailInfo');
        break;
      case 'sell':
        console.log('sell');
        break;
      case 'event':
        console.log('event');
        break;
    }
  }
```

how can i transfer a value od id to function? id is not defined

Comment: `(click)="renderView(id)` is not valid html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass element ID to Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292176/pass-element-id-to-javascript-function)

Comment: It should be onclick, not (click)

Answer (score 1):

The code you have mentioned will not work as intended.

Rewrite it as:

HTML:

```
<a class="nav-link" id="sell" onclick="renderView(this.id)" 
<a class="nav-link" id="event" onclick="renderView(this.id)"
```

JS remains same:

```
renderView(id) {
    switch (id) {
      case 'detailInfo':
        console.log('detailInfo');
        break;
      case 'sell':
        console.log('sell');
        break;
      case 'event':
        console.log('event');
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: renderView is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: @ArekSzumacher how are you adding the function in? how do you include the script? this shouldn't cause that error if you've included your JS correctly ...

Comment: @ArekSzumacher did you get it right? I hope you have added the js function renderView in the same HTML page or in a JS file which is referenced in the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use onClick e.g.:

```
<a class="nav-link" id="sell" onclick="renderView(this.id)">
```

then in simply check in code

```
function renderView(id) {
   switch (id) {
     case 'detailInfo':
      console.log('detailInfo');
      break;
    case 'sell':
      console.log('sell');
      break;
    case 'event':
      console.log('event');
      break;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: renderView is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick   but transfer this.id to function

Comment: Kindly check updated answer and see if same error occurs and do use function keyword. @ArekSzumacher

Answer (score 0):

First, change (click) to onclick, as (click) is invalid HTML. Also add text and a closing tag.

Second, perform the function on this.id:

```
<a class="nav-link" id="sell" onclick="renderId(this.id)">Sell</a>
```