# document.getElementById with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I have six buttons and I want to have all in one function. For each button is a different div available and if I click for example the third button, then should pop up the div for the third button.

javascript:

```
function kfunc(){
    var x = document.getElementById("id1"||"id2"||"id3"||"id4"||"id5" || "id6")
    x.style.display = 'block';
    x;
}

function closefunc(){
    document.getElementById("id1"||"id2"||"id3"||"id4"||"id5" || "id6").style.display = 'none';
}

function testfunc(){
    alert("test");
}
```

HTML:

```
    <button id="btn1" onclick="kfunc()">Küche</button>
    <button id="btn2" onclick="kfunc()">Bad</button>
    <button id="btn3" onclick="kfunc()">Wohnzimmer</button>
    <button id="btn4" onclick="kfunc()">Melina</button>
    <button id="btn5" onclick="kfunc()">Kleines Bad</button>
    <button id="btn6" onclick="kfunc()">Schlafzimmer</button>

<!-- Küche -->
<div class="frame_kueche" id="id1">
    <div class="buttons_close">
        <button onclick="closefunc()">X</button>
    </div>
    <button onclick="testfunc()">ab</button>
</div>
<!-- Bad -->
<div class="frame_bad" id="id2">
    <div class="buttons_close">
        <button onclick="closefunc()">X</button>
    </div>
    <button onclick="testfunc()">a</button>
</div>
<!-- Wohnzimmer -->
<div class="frame_wohnzimmer" id="id3">
    <div class="buttons_close">
        <button onclick="closefunc()">X</button>
    </div>
    <button onclick="testfunc()">a</button>
</div>
<!-- Melina -->
<div class="frame_melina" id="id4">
    <div class="buttons_close">
        <button onclick="closefunc()">X</button>
    </div>
    <button onclick="testfunc()">a</button>
</div>
<!-- kleines Bad -->
<div class="frame_kleines_bad" id="id5">
    <div class="buttons_close">
        <button onclick="closefunc()">X</button>
    </div>
    <button onclick="testfunc()">a</button>
</div>
<!-- Schlafzimmer -->
<div class="frame_schlafzimmer" id="id6">
    <div class="buttons_close">
        <button onclick="closefunc()">X</button>
    </div>
    <button onclick="testfunc()">a</button>
</div>
```

It works almost! Logically when there is id1 available, it will use id1 and not the others. How can I fix it? Like I said: When btn3 is clicked then the div with id3 should show up but it always shows id1.

Comment: In addition: I guess I have to use arrays

Comment: can you please use single quotation just like this document.getElementById('id1' || 'id2' || 'id3' || 'id4' || 'id5' || 'id6')

Comment: why don't you pass in the id instead of using an array? Look at the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17292291/1675954)

Answer (score 2):

Look at your javascript. Actually you don't need to set id attribute for your buttons.

Just add your **frame id** as parameter to `kfunc` and `closefunc` function. Like this:

```
function kfunc(id) { 
    console.log(id)
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block'
}

function closefunc(id) {
    console.log(id)
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'
}
```

Usage:

```
onclick="kfunc('id1')"
onclick="closefunc('id1')"
```

---

Note: My solution is **not** tested. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: This only works for the first button. The other 5 buttons do nothing.

Comment: change the other button onclick parameter. 'id1' to 'id2' or 'id3' or whatever frame id you want to attach to a button.

Comment: I did but nothing happens to the other 5. Do you want to see my full code?

Comment: Ah I fixed it. In my CSS file was only a class for frame_kueche

Answer (score 2):

If you change your html to include a data attribute in the buttons, and to also pass 'this' in your onClick function call

```
<button id="btn1" data-div="id1" onclick="kfunc(this)">Küche</button>
<button id="btn2" data-div="id2" onclick="kfunc(this)">Bad</button>
```

And then in your function you can check which button was pressed, and display the appropriate div.

```
function kfunc(thispass) {
     let fish = thispass.getAttribute('data-div');
     document.getElementById(fish).style.display = 'block';
}
```

As for the close button. If you give all of the divs a common class, you can hide them all at once.

Comment: This only works for the first button. The other 5 buttons do nothing.

Comment: I only gave the example for the first two buttons, you just need to add data-div="DivID" to each of the other buttons. But to be honest, Faris Han's answer is more elegant ;D

Answer (score 1):

You can't use getElementById like this. you should use getElementByClassName or you can use the code below:

```js
function kfunc(id){
        var btn = id;
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }

    function closefunc(id){
        var selectedDiv = id;
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }

    function testfunc(){
        alert("test");
    }
```

```css
div[class^= "frame"]{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="kfunc('id1')">Küche</button>
    <button id="btn2" onclick="kfunc('id2')">Bad</button>
    <button id="btn3" onclick="kfunc('id3')">Wohnzimmer</button>
    <button id="btn4" onclick="kfunc('id4')">Melina</button>
    <button id="btn5" onclick="kfunc('id5')">Kleines Bad</button>
    <button id="btn6" onclick="kfunc('id6')">Schlafzimmer</button>
    
    <!-- Küche -->
    <div class="frame_kueche" id="id1">
        <div class="buttons_close">
            <button onclick="closefunc('id1')">X</button>
        </div>
        <button onclick="testfunc()">ab</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Bad -->
    <div class="frame_bad" id="id2">
        <div class="buttons_close">
            <button onclick="closefunc('id2')">X</button>
        </div>
        <button onclick="testfunc()">a</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Wohnzimmer -->
    <div class="frame_wohnzimmer" id="id3">
        <div class="buttons_close">
            <button onclick="closefunc('id3')">X</button>
        </div>
        <button onclick="testfunc()">a</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Melina -->
    <div class="frame_melina" id="id4">
        <div class="buttons_close">
            <button onclick="closefunc('id4')">X</button>
        </div>
        <button onclick="testfunc()">a</button>
    </div>
    <!-- kleines Bad -->
    <div class="frame_kleines_bad" id="id5">
        <div class="buttons_close">
            <button onclick="closefunc('id5')">X</button>
        </div>
        <button onclick="testfunc()">a</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Schlafzimmer -->
    <div class="frame_schlafzimmer" id="id6">
        <div class="buttons_close">
            <button onclick="closefunc('id6')">X</button>
        </div>
        <button onclick="testfunc()">a</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: This only works for the first button. The other 5 buttons do nothing.

Comment: Run the code snippet. It works for all buttons. I have checked it before posting. wish it also works fine for you.